# pandas resample with global minimum and maximum specifying the filling method

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I want to resample a dataset, the minimum date of each series should be the same for each series, therefore, the minimum date of each series should be the minimum value for the *date* column. Same for the maximum date (Instead of resampling at series level, I want to resample taking the global maximum value).

And this, opens a new question, how do I specify when resampling that the null values that I want a 0.

I mean, suppose this case:

| series col | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| series_1 | 2023-02-06 | 5 |
| series_1 | 2023-02-23 | 7 |

If you notice, I miss the series in between: (resampling on weeks)

| series col | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| series_1 | 2023-02-13 | 0 |

I'm wondering what is the following code doing? how is filling that value? Because I have not specified anything and I don't see null values when I'm resampling.[pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.resample.html)

```
df.groupby('series_col').resample('W', on='date', label='left', loffset=pd.DateOffset(days=0))['value'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? And provide a reproducible input as DataFrame constructor (I imagine the date column has a datetime type).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a weak calendar table as a dimension and do a full join on your data

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).